# How can I upload image to database with react-image-upload dependency?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, file-upload, mern

I need to upload images to mongodb database with form. When I fill form with image, the image not add to database. rest of details pass to the database except image. How can I fix this issue?
I post my code with here. Can someone help me to fix this please?
I used [React-file-base64 dependancy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-base64).

```
function ItemForm(props) {

const [details, setDetails] = useState({
    topic: "",
    description: "",
    date: "",
    time: "",
    image: ""
});

function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(name);
    setDetails(prevValue => {
        return {
            ...prevValue,
            [name]: value
        };
    });
}

function handleClick(event) {
    props.addWorkshops(details);
    setDetails({
        topic: "",
        description: "",
        date: "",
        time: "",
        image: ""
    });

    event.preventDefault();
}

const classes = useStyles();
return (
    <div>
        <form>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <TextField name="topic" id="mui-theme-provider-outlined-input" className={classes.margin} label="Workshop name" variant="outlined" fullWidth size="small" onChange={handleChange} value={details.title} />
                <TextField name="description" id="mui-theme-provider-outlined-input" className={classes.margin} multiline rows={4} label="Description" variant="outlined" fullWidth size="small" onChange={handleChange} value={details.description} />
                <TextField name="date" type="date" id="mui-theme-provider-outlined-input" className={classes.margin} label="Date" variant="outlined" fullWidth size="small" onChange={handleChange} InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                }} />
                <TextField name="time" type="time" id="mui-theme-provider-outlined-input" className={classes.margin} label="Time" variant="outlined" fullWidth size="small" onChange={handleChange} InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                }} />

                <FileBase
                    type="file"
                    multiple={false}
                    name="image"
                    onDone={handleClick}
                />

            </ThemeProvider>
            <Button type="submit" onClick={() => {
                handleClick();
            }} size="large" variant="contained" style={buttonColor}>Schedule <UilStopwatch style={{ marginLeft: "5%" }} /> </Button>
        </form>
    </div>

 )
}
```

Thank you

Console screenshot
[image: Console log]

Answer (score 0):

set your details like this

```
 let data = new FormData();
      data.append('topic', topic);
      data.append('description', description);
      data.append('date', date);
      data.append('time', time);
      data.append('image', image);
setDetails(data)
```

in my case I am sending this data to server like this

```
export const createCategory = (data, handleClose) => async dispatch => {
  // console.log(data, ':yes');
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_CATEGORY_LOADING,
    payload: true
  });
  axios
    .post(`${API_PATH}/admin/categories`, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      // console.log(res.data, 'creating category data');
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_CATEGORY,
        payload: res.data.data
      });
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_CATEGORY_LOADING,
        payload: false
      });
      dispatch(getCategory());
      toast.success(res.data.message);
      handleClose(false);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // console.log(err, 'Error creating category data');
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_CATEGORY,
        payload: false
      });
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_CATEGORY_LOADING,
        payload: false
      });
      toast.error(err.response.data.message);
    });
};
```

try this

```
const handleClick=(files)=>{
// if your are getting files array then below code is fine otherwise write files instead of files[0]
setState({...details,image:files[0]})
}
```

Comment: Hello Ali. Thank you for answering. Where should I change? Inside handleClick function?

Comment: where is your api request

Comment: post this data to API

Comment: You need to pass this data in this function ```props.addWorkshops(details);```

Comment: api request is another componet. When I submitted this form topic,description,date and time are passed to the database. Only image is not passed.

Comment: Are you getting image in state?

Comment: No, I add a screenshot of consloe.log. When I submit the  form

Comment: Thank you Ali, I could fix the issue. The problem was inside the handleChange function. It's not be handleClick. It should be handleChange.
Than you so much for helping

Comment: You passed handleClick to on Done thats why i am telling this you can change this to handleFile

Comment: You are using the same function for file select and sunmit data I think it not the actual behavior which you want